# PHP str_replace array

Tags: php, arrays

i had a problem about returning an array into a spesified string. so, this is my code that i had been try.

```
$setValues = array("test1", "test2", "testurl");
$change = join("','", $setValues);    
$done = str_replace("", "?", $change);
```

so, the $change variable will return an array something like this :

```
'test1', 'test2', 'testurl'
```

i want to change that array into something like this :

```
?, ?, ?
```

is it possible to doing this?

Comment: Uh, what? Could you please clarify what you mean? You want to replace the text with question marks?

Comment: Just set all the values to `?` !!

Comment: i know that one, but i got a situation that not allowing me to doing that methods, it's actually a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use array_map() with callback

```
    $setValues = array("test1", "test2", "testurl");
    $change = array_map(function($val) { return "?"; }, $setValues);
    $change = join(",", $change); 
    echo $change;// outputs => ?,?,?
```

Comment: simple, and very straight forward. thanks Mr. Niranjan!

Comment: You can simply do it `echo implode(',',array_map(function($val){ return "?";},$setValues));`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you-

```
function myfunction($num)
{
   return '?';
}

$setValues = array("test1", "test2", "testurl");
$setValues = array_map("myfunction",$setValues);
$change = join("','", $setValues);    
$done = str_replace("", "?", $change);
```

Comment: this returns `test1','test2','testurl`

Comment: this one also working, awesome method. thanks Mr. Rohit!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating with `array_map` seems way too overkill for this. You're basically trying to generate `n` questionmarks, given that `n = count($array)`. So why not just:

```
$questionmarks = join( "," , array_fill( 0, count( $array ), "?" ) );
```